# How to get a drop-down menu to overlay other Item

Tags: html, css, menu, overlay

I am creating drop-down menu. However when I hover on it, the menu push all content down. I just want to overlay all content below.
When I try set `position: absolute;` for the `sub-menu`, seem work but it remove all style, color.. of control.

Please help me to get this.

**Here is the code:**

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Varela Round';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Varela Round Regular'), local('VarelaRound-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/varelaround/v13/w8gdH283Tvk__Lua32TysjIfp8uK.ttf) format('truetype');
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
:root {
  --accent-color: #45494e;
  --gradient-color: #fbfbfb;
}
a:focus {
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
}
a:focus:after {
  width: 50px;
}
a:after {
  content: "";
  background: #fbfbfb;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
body {
  background: #45494e;
  font-family: "Varela Round", Nunito, Montserrat, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.menu {
  margin: 15px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.menu > ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu > ol > li {
  background: #3c3c3c;
  border-left: 5px solid var(--gradient-color);
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.menu > ol > li:nth-child(1) {
  --accent-color: #fda085;
  --gradient-color: #f6d365;
}
.menu > ol > li:nth-child(2) {
  --accent-color: #bff098;
  --gradient-color: #6fd6ff;
}
.menu > ol > li:nth-child(3) {
  --accent-color: #ea8d8d;
  --gradient-color: #a890fe;
}
.menu > ol > li:nth-child(4) {
  --accent-color: #d8b5ff;
  --gradient-color: #1eae98;
}
.menu > ol > li:nth-child(5) {
  --accent-color: #c6ea8d;
  --gradient-color: #fe90af;
}
.menu > ol > li a {
  color: #fbfbfb;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
.menu > ol > li a:not(:last-child):before {
  content: "\f078";
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.menu > ol > li:focus,
.menu > ol > li:focus-within,
.menu > ol > li:hover {
  z-index: 100;
}
.menu > ol > li:focus:after,
.menu > ol > li:focus-within:after,
.menu > ol > li:hover:after {
  max-width: 800px;
}
.menu > ol > li:focus .sub-menu,
.menu > ol > li:focus-within .sub-menu {
  max-height: 500px;
}
.menu > ol > li:focus a:before,
.menu > ol > li:focus-within a:before {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.menu > ol > li:after {
  background: #3c3c3c;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  max-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.menu > ol .menu-item {
  position: relative;
}
.menu > ol .sub-menu {
  border-left: 1px solid #fbfbfb;
  margin-left: 22.5px;
  list-style: none;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 7.5px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 1;
}
.menu > ol .sub-menu li {
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
.menu > ol .sub-menu li:hover,
.menu > ol .sub-menu li a:focus {
  background: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.3);
}
.menu > ol .sub-menu li a:after {
  bottom: 5px;
  height: 1px;
}
.menu > ol .sub-menu li a:hover:after,
.menu > ol .sub-menu li a:focus:after {
  width: 15px;
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  a:focus,
  a:hover {
    position: relative;
  }
  a:focus:after,
  a:hover:after {
    width: 50px;
  }
  a:after {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .menu {
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0vh;
  }
  .menu > ol {
    display: block;
    max-width: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .menu > ol > li {
    border-top: 5px solid var(--accent-color);
    border-left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 120px;
  }
  .menu > ol > li:hover:after,
  .menu > ol > li:focus:after,
  .menu > ol > li:focus-within:after {
    border-radius: 3px;
    top: -15px;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: -15px;
    right: -15px;
  }
  .menu > ol > li:hover .sub-menu,
  .menu > ol > li:focus .sub-menu,
  .menu > ol > li:focus-within .sub-menu {
    max-height: 750px;
  }
  .menu > ol > li a:not(:last-child):before {
    right: 12.5px;
  }
  .menu > ol > li:hover a:before {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
  .menu > ol .sub-menu {
    border-left: 0;
    margin: 15px -15px -15px;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 775px) {
  .menu > ol > li {
    width: 150px;
  }
  .menu > ol > li a:not(:last-child):before {
    right: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table style="height: 100%; border:solid;
        vertical-align: top; ">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <nav class="menu">
              <ol>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Home</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">About</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                  <a href="#0">Widgets</a>
                  <ol class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Big Widgets</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Bigger Widgets</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Huge Widgets</a></li>
                  </ol>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                  <a href="#0">Kabobs</a>
                  <ol class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Shishkabobs</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">BBQ kabobs</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Summer kabobs</a></li>
                  </ol>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Contact</a></li>
              </ol>
            </nav>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Other Item
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your inline styles in your 2nd `<table>` tag and try adding the below to your css. For better understanding I have given an ID to each `tr` so you can understand the styling below

HTML structure

```
  <table>
    <tr id="menu-items-wrapper">
      <td>
        Menu Items
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="content-wrapper">
      <td>
        Other Item
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Added styling

```
  #menu-items-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    border: solid;
    height: 130px;
  }

  #content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 135px; /*change according to your media breakpoint*/
  }
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Varela Round';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Varela Round Regular'), local('VarelaRound-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/varelaround/v13/w8gdH283Tvk__Lua32TysjIfp8uK.ttf) format('truetype');
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --accent-color: #45494e;
  --gradient-color: #fbfbfb;
}

a:focus {
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
}

a:focus:after {
  width: 50px;
}

a:after {
  content: "";
  background: #fbfbfb;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

body {
  background: #45494e;
  font-family: "Varela Round", Nunito, Montserrat, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.menu {
  margin: 15px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.menu>ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu>ol>li {
  background: #3c3c3c;
  border-left: 5px solid var(--gradient-color);
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu>ol>li:nth-child(1) {
  --accent-color: #fda085;
  --gradient-color: #f6d365;
}

.menu>ol>li:nth-child(2) {
  --accent-color: #bff098;
  --gradient-color: #6fd6ff;
}

.menu>ol>li:nth-child(3) {
  --accent-color: #ea8d8d;
  --gradient-color: #a890fe;
}

.menu>ol>li:nth-child(4) {
  --accent-color: #d8b5ff;
  --gradient-color: #1eae98;
}

.menu>ol>li:nth-child(5) {
  --accent-color: #c6ea8d;
  --gradient-color: #fe90af;
}

.menu>ol>li a {
  color: #fbfbfb;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu>ol>li a:not(:last-child):before {
  content: "\f078";
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu>ol>li:focus,
.menu>ol>li:focus-within,
.menu>ol>li:hover {
  z-index: 100;
}

.menu>ol>li:focus:after,
.menu>ol>li:focus-within:after,
.menu>ol>li:hover:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, var(--accent-color), var(--gradient-color));
  max-width: 800px;
}

.menu>ol>li:focus .sub-menu,
.menu>ol>li:focus-within .sub-menu {
  max-height: 500px;
}

.menu>ol>li:focus a:before,
.menu>ol>li:focus-within a:before {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.menu>ol>li:after {
  background: #3c3c3c;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  max-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu>ol .menu-item {
  position: relative;
}

.menu>ol .sub-menu {
  border-left: 1px solid #fbfbfb;
  margin-left: 22.5px;
  list-style: none;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 7.5px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu>ol .sub-menu li {
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.menu>ol .sub-menu li:hover,
.menu>ol .sub-menu li a:focus {
  background: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.3);
}

.menu>ol .sub-menu li a:after {
  bottom: 5px;
  height: 1px;
}

.menu>ol .sub-menu li a:hover:after,
.menu>ol .sub-menu li a:focus:after {
  width: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {

  a:focus,
  a:hover {
    position: relative;
  }

  a:focus:after,
  a:hover:after {
    width: 50px;
  }

  a:after {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
  }

  .menu {
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0vh;
  }

  .menu>ol {
    display: block;
    max-width: none;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .menu>ol>li {
    border-top: 5px solid var(--accent-color);
    border-left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 120px;
  }

  .menu>ol>li:hover:after,
  .menu>ol>li:focus:after,
  .menu>ol>li:focus-within:after {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--accent-color), var(--gradient-color));
    border-radius: 3px;
    top: -15px;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: -15px;
    right: -15px;
  }

  .menu>ol>li:hover .sub-menu,
  .menu>ol>li:focus .sub-menu,
  .menu>ol>li:focus-within .sub-menu {
    max-height: 750px;
  }

  .menu>ol>li a:not(:last-child):before {
    right: 12.5px;
  }

  .menu>ol>li:hover a:before {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }

  .menu>ol .sub-menu {
    border-left: 0;
    margin: 15px -15px -15px;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 775px) {
  .menu>ol>li {
    width: 150px;
  }

  .menu>ol>li a:not(:last-child):before {
    right: 25px;
  }
}

#menu-items-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  border: solid;
  height: 130px;
}

#content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 135px;
  /*change according to your media breakpoint*/
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="menu-items-wrapper">
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <nav class="menu">
              <ol>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Home</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">About</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                  <a href="#0">Widgets</a>
                  <ol class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Big Widgets</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Bigger Widgets</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Huge Widgets</a></li>
                  </ol>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                  <a href="#0">Kabobs</a>
                  <ol class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Shishkabobs</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">BBQ kabobs</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Summer kabobs</a></li>
                  </ol>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Contact</a></li>
              </ol>
            </nav>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="content-wrapper">
    <td>
      Other Item
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's perfect answer. Thank you very much! I appreciate it. Now I understand the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This will surely work try it once, if more modification is needed feel free to comment down. :)

Just remove these line they are of no use -

```
.menu > ol .sub-menu li:hover,
.menu > ol .sub-menu li a:focus {
  background: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.3);
}
.menu > ol .sub-menu li a:hover:after,
.menu > ol .sub-menu li a:focus:after {
  width: 15px;
}
```

And edit

```
.menu > ol .sub-menu li {
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

as (change color accordingly)

```
.menu > ol .sub-menu li,
.menu > ol .sub-menu li:hover,
.menu > ol .sub-menu li a:focus {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  background: rgba(60, 60, 60);
  width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: ohh I see.. okk let me check cozz its working on my system. But I guess u have already found the soluton. :)